# How to insert binary data to SQL using Laravel 5.*

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I would like to save an image into a varbinary(max) field in MSSQL.

The store method in my controller looks like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $vorname = $request->input('vorname');

        $nachname = $request->input('nachname');

        $file = $request->file('avatar');

        $extension = $file->clientExtension();

        $fullname = $nachname . "_" . $vorname . "." . $extension;

        $file->storeAs('avatars' , $fullname);

        $path = storage_path() . "\app\avatars\\". $fullname;

        $imageData = unpack("H*", file_get_contents($path));

        Mitarbeiter::create([

            'PersonalNr' => request('personalnr'),
            'Mitarbeiterschluessel' => request('mitarbeiterkey'),
            'Vorname' => $vorname,
            'Familienname' => $nachname,
            'Bild' => $imageData[1]

        ]);

        return view('welcome');

    }
```

I'm getting an error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Die implizite Konvertierung vom nvarchar(max)-Datentyp in
>   varbinary(max) ist nicht zulässig.

translated:

> Implicit conversion from the nvarchar (max) data type to varbinary
>   (max) is not allowed.

Comment: An off-topic question, why are you trying to store the image in the database? Laravel offers a great Storage API, why don't you use it? Any particular reason?

Answer (score 2):

this code work for me

```
if($request->input('Image')){
    $datastring = file_get_contents($request->input('Image'));
    $data         = unpack("H*hex", $datastring);
    $data         = '0x'.$data['hex'];
    $photo = \App\TraineeImage::where('ID', 13)->first();
    $photo->update(['Image' =>  \DB::raw("CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), $data) ") ]);
}
```

Comment: This worked for me after weeks of struggling to CAST the binary data

Answer (score 2):

I recently came across similar requirement and did it like this.
(Assuming $base64String is your string that contains image in base64 format)

```php
$sql = "CAST(N'' AS xml).VALUE('xs:base64Binary(\"".$base64String."\")', 'VARBINARY(max)')";

UserProfilePicture::updateOrCreate(
    ['user_id' => $this->user_id],
    [
        'type' => $type,
        'size' => $size,
        'data' => DB::raw($sql),
    ],
);
```

Comment: after more than a week... this is the best solution

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminIni

Answer (score 1):

I am faced with the same problem, but I figured out a way to make it work with Laravel's DB class.

Basically just like in any other language certain types cannot be implicitly converted, so are the types of MSSQL. Here is an image of all of the type conversion for MSSQL. [image]
Notice that **From** *nvarchar* **To** *varbinary* you can only do **Explicit conversion**.

Since in PHP you don't have "binary" type and simply a **string**, we cannot store it directly into MSSQL. To solve this problem, we need to manually/**explicitly cast** our image into a *binary/varbinary*. Reading from [conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine) of [binary/varbinary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql) we need to call **CAST** or **CONVERT** on our image.

And since we want to do prepared statements, we can say `CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), ?)` and then bind it to the image value.

```
DB::statement(
    "INSERT INTO files (PersonalNr, Mitarbeiterschluessel, Vorname, Familienname, Bild) VALUES (?,?,?,?,CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), ?));", [
        request('personalnr'),
        request('mitarbeiterkey'),
        $vorname,
        $nachname,
        base64_encode(file_get_contents($path))
]);
```

Notice that I don't do any pack/unpack, but simply base64_encode'ed string, because as I understand you cannot pass binary from PHP to SQL that easily.

Answer (score 0):

i know that this topics is very old but, this was my fix

```
$doc = file_get_contents($path);
$data = unpack("H*hex", $doc);
DB::connection("sqlsrv")->statement("INSERT INTO tb_docs (id, doc) VALUES (?,0x".$data['hex'].");",[$id]);
```

the field "doc" have as data type varbinary(max) without attribute FILESTREAM, in this field i stored files like JPG, PNG, PDF and work very well