# Laravel: Base64 Image not Uploading

Tags: php, laravel

Using Laravel and PHP, I am trying to add a photo to a database. This database only takes `base64` images.

I take a given file, verify that it's an image type (png, jpg, etc.) and try to encode it as a `base64` image. Then I try to upload it to the database with other details about the object.

However, this isn't working. Instead I am told of a data type mismatch:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 Implicit conversion from data
>   type varchar(max) to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT
>   function to run this query. [20018] (severity 16)

My code absolutely works when I remove the 'photo' value from the insertion. So I'm wondering what it is that could be the problem with what I'm doing.

See below my laravel controller function.

```
public function addStudent(Request $request) {
    $courses = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    $statuses = [1,2,3,4];

    $validated = Validator::make($request->all(), [
      "submit"      => "required",
      "student_id"  => ["required", "integer", "regex:/^[0-9]+$/"],
      "forename"    => ["required", "regex: /^[a-zA-Z’'. -]+$/"],
      "surname"     => ["required", "regex: /^[a-zA-Z’'. -]+$/"],
      "course_id"   => ["required", Rule::in([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) ],
      "status_id"   => ["required", Rule::in([1, 2, 3, 4]) ],
      /*Image validation done here: must be of the types below
      Since this part passes, I know I am working with an image */
      "photo"       => "required|image|file:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048"
]);
$errors = $validated->errors();
if($validated->fails()) {
  return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->all())->withErrors($errors);
}
$data = $request->all();

/* Here I try to encode the image as base64 */
if ($request->hasFile("photo")) {
  if($request->file("photo")->isValid()) {
    $file = $request->file('photo');
    $image = base64_encode($file);
    $image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->file('photo')));
    if (!($image)) {
      echo "<h3>Image null!</h3>";
    }
  }
} else {
  echo "<h3>Request doesn't have photo</h3>";
}
/*Try to upload values to database, return errors if fail */
try {
  $insert =
  DB::table('CCEAGpoc.dbo.Student')->insert([
    ['student_id'  => $data['student_id'],
    'forename'    => $data['forename'],
    'surname'     => $data['surname'],
    'course_id'   => $data['course_id'],
    'photo'       => $image,
    'status_id'   => $data['status_id']]
  ]);
  return view('success');
} catch (Exception $ex) { 
  return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->all())->withErrors($errors);
}
```

For full clarity, my form looks like the following:

```
<form action="submitAdd" method="post" class="form-inline" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @csrf
  ...
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="photo">Photo: </label>
        <input type="file" name="photo" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Student" />
  </div>
</form>
```

I am honestly not sure what it is about the above that is causing the error. If anyone could help, I'd be hugely thankful.

Comment: Could you show the migration that creates the photo field in the database?

Comment: Storing whole images inside your db is seldom a good idea.  Why not uploading your files to your server and then storing the image's path inside your db?

Comment: AndreaGolin I'll bring that up, though whether I can opt for that route isn't my call to make. Thanks for the advice.

@AdrianHernandez-Lopez Sure, I'll edit it into the post in a moment.

Comment: What is the type of  the 'photo' table field?

Comment: @AndreaGolin The type I'm testing with is .png, though it's meant to be valid for any image type as in the validator

Comment: The migration you posted is the insert error. Could you post the migration that creates the table (or add the field to the table)?

Comment: Nope, i mean, the SQL table field. It should be TEXT or BLOB

Comment: @AdrianHernandez-Lopez Did I not do that already with the $insert value? Apologies if I'm being slow on the take

AndreaGolin, my bad. Its data type is varbinary

Comment: No, I mean migration file. More info at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations

Comment: Apologies @AdrianHernandez-Lopez . I don't have a migration file since I'm working with an external server DB

Comment: Then, could you show the table structure? @AndreaGolin is asking pointing also to the table structure: TEXT or BLOB instead of VARCHAR.

Comment: @AdrianHernandez-Lopez AndreaGolbin 
I gladly can: 
student_id(int)
forename, surname, course_id (nvarchar), 
photo(varbinary(max),null) 
and lastly, status_id(int)

Comment: So, as @AndreaGolin pointed. Change the photo field to TEXT or BLOB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must decode your base64 string to binary prior to insert it onto varbinary field, as it will accept only `binary` data.

The base64 permits a safe binary file transmission, but it is not a valid binary value for mssql varbinary, as it is a string type.

```
DECLARE @string varchar(20)

SET @string = 'Hello World'

SELECT CONVERT(varbinary, @string)
```

Also, if your are actually using mssql, you should add mssql tag to your question accordingly, there a lot of people with a lot of mssql skills out there (mssql its not my typical day to day database, my knowledge of it is seriously limitated) that are missing your question.

Comment: Thank you! I'm just looking to write this in PHP/laravel now and I'll confirm if it worked

Comment: @NoStupidQuestions maybe give this a try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48261495/how-to-insert-binary-data-to-sql-using-laravel-5

Comment: It's working! My solution was similar to something there:

`$datastring = file_get_contents($request->file('photo')); $unpack = unpack("H*hex", $datastring); $unpack = '0x'.$unpack['hex'];`

`$answer = DB::raw("CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), $unpack)");`

Then I use $answer in the insert command down below.

Thanks again for your help!